What is avail_out minimum possible value for inflate in zlib z_stream?
I checked the zlib example at https://zlib.net/zpipe.c and I've seen that chunk size of 16384 bytes is used. But what is minimal possible chunk size for output inflate data could be used? Can I use for example output buffer with size 1024 or 2048 bytes? And what is the minimal possible returned avail_out after inflate if I use these values?
I tried to search for this information but could not find any information.

One.
It is always possible for avail_out to be zero on return, i.e., the output buffer has been filled.

Thank you Mark! Last one question is it possible if I use output buffer with value of 1024 bytes may it return 1024, so no data were written? Are there any restrictions for minimal buffer value?
To be more precise in the example above I suppose that sliding window buffer is full of input data (32 Kbytes).

Yes, it's possible, but you would have had to provided only a tiny snippet of compressed data that happened to have no decoded bytes in it. inflate doesn't wait for anything to fill to provide data. As soon as it decodes a byte or a match, it writes the decompressed data to the output buffer.
